# ElasticNet and SGDClassifier(loss='log') with l1 producing very different results from LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')

Tags: scikit-learn

For Scikit-learn I have

```
c = 0.001 
lr = LogisticRegression(C=c,penalty='l1')  
en = ElasticNet(l1_ratio = 1, alpha=1./c)  
sgdc = SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=1./c,penalty='l1', l1_ratio=1)
```

For LogisticRegression **C** is the inverse regularization factor so it represents **1/lambda**. 
In the case for ElasticNet **alpha** is the inverse of **C**. The problem arises when I compare the trained model and prediction scores for ***en*** and ***sgdc*** as compared to ***lr***.

In all cases the accuracy is far lower. When I try to calculate the roc_auc_score I get an exception warning saying that the predicted results are all in 1 class. Obviously this doesn't make sense as with LogisticRegression I can get meaningful results.

I have seen the page on ElasticNet on Scikit-learn where it says that lambda = a + b and l1_ratio = a/(a+b). So when l1_ratio = 1, 1/lambda should behave as C in LogisticRegression.

My question then is whether I am setting up ElasticNet() and SGDClassifier() incorrectly? If so how can I set them up so that they emulate LogisticRegression?

Comment: Contrary to the two others, `ElasticNet` uses a least squares data loss and not a logistic loss, so the results will inevitably be different. As far as the two logistic regressions are concerned, `lr` finds a global optimum of the loss given all the data, whereas `sgdc` does gradient descent using the samples. The latter converges towards a minimal expected loss over the data distribution in the infinite data limit. It may just not have converged yet, you could try adding more epochs, but still, the results are not guaranteed to be the same as those of `lr`.

Comment: There might still be a discrepancy in the parameterization (alpha vs C and their meaning). Would be worth doing extensive empirical evaluation

Comment: additionally, in some cases the scaling is not `alpha = 1. / c` but `alpha * n_samples  = 1. / c`

Comment: But the results are very different, it is not just like an accuracy difference of like +/- 7%. It's like 20%. In the past I have implemented batch gradient descent and stochastic gradient for some classification algorithms and I have never experienced situations where they are very different.

It also strikes me as odd that it sometimes predicts everything as 1 class, leading me unable to use roc_auc.

Comment: @eickenberg
With epoch = 5 does that mean that it only runs over all the samples 5 times? That seems very low.

Comment: For ElasticNet, eickenberg is right with pointing out the different loss. That is not the whole story, though, as ElasticNet is a regressor and the other two are classifiers. So if you have a multi-class problem, the algorithms will do vastly different things. For SGD: have you played with the number of episodes or the learning rate? If you don't have a huge amount of data, the default number of episodes might be much too low.

Comment: @AndreasMueller I have around 1300 samples and 5400 features, what sort of epoch should I pick given samples vs features?

Comment: I don't really have a rule of thumb, sorry. Maybe just monitor the error (verbose setting). Also, that doesn't seem so much data, so just set is as high as your patience allows and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @AndreasMueller I am now using GridSearchCV instead with 25 iterations for the SGDClassifier(). I set the scoring to 'roc_auc' and it strikes me as odd that the optimal alpha value computed is the smallest one that I provide. Wouldn't that not make sense? I am trying to search for a good regularization factor. If it's too small it basically means I'm not regularizing.